# Error during file upload : The specific key does not exists

Tags: acumatica

While uploading a customization package. I am getting an error

**Error during file upload : The specific key does not exists**

I have removed the customization package and once again added the package. I am still getting is error.

[image]

Comment: could be something built incorrect in your page modifications. Did you edit the page manually (modify the XML or the project.xml file) or maybe crossing versions. What version are you importing to? what version was the package build int (shows in project.xml)?

Comment: This package works fine in local instance. The package build and applied on 2017 R2. I am using Visual studio 15 for compiling my project. Framework 4.5.2  and C# 6.0

Comment: if there is no trace details then I would start removing some of your recent changes or items from your customization project zip file to determine which item is missing in the customization package. I would start with page entries. For example if you modified sales order page, remove that page from the project.xml and see if it works (import the zip). If it imports then start to peel back some of the changes in the sales order page (or any page you have modified). just a thought. The problem is there is little detail provided in the error to know for sure

Comment: I have tried applying the package on fresh installation and it went through without any issue.

Comment: I got a better idea, maybe Acumatica could actually try to implement some proper backward compatability and better error tracing? We shouldn't have to waste our time with this stuff, especially for minor version upgrades!!!